# IOS Animated UINavigationController Global Background Image

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the following in my Navigation Controller Load event...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.jpg"];
CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 620));
UIImage* part = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:part];
[self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
```

This sets the background image and works fine once I have set the embedded view to have a clear background. My question is how do I alter this image once it is loaded?

The effect I am looking for is that I want to crop a new section of the image when different views are pushed onto the stack.

I know I could load a new image for each table but the desired effect I want is so that when you push to the next view, the table moves from right to left showing the new table, but the background moves right to left only a little bit.

Ended up using NSTimer and this combined

```
[[self.navigationController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
[self.navigationController.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tag to different your backgroundView and other views

```
#deifne BACKGROUNDVIEWTAG  999
if(![self.view subviews] || ((UIView *)[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).tag != BACKGROUNDVIEWTAG)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.jpg"];
    CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 620));
    UIImage* part = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:part];
    imageView.tag = BACKGROUNDVIEWTAG;
    [self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Im not quite sure how this helps, but I will have a play around.

Comment: I am going to give it the answer, but I went for this in the end     [[self.navigationController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    [self.navigationController.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];